# Recursive CTE with uniqueidentifier must have value in an anchor

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
;WITH Companies(pkCompanyID,name,parentCompanyID,SomeId) AS

        (
            SELECT
                tblCompany.pkCompanyID,
                tblCompany.name,
                NULL,--this is a int with no value and it works in the anchor
                NULL AS SomeId--But this uniqueidentifier do not work why?
            FROM
                tblCompany
            WHERE
                tblCompany.fkCompToCompID IS NULL
            UNION ALL
            SELECT
                tblCompany.pkCompanyID,
                tblCompany.name,
                tblCompany.fkCompToCompID,
                NEWID()
            FROM
                tblCompany
                JOIN Companies ON tblCompany.fkCompToCompID=Companies.pkCompanyID
        )
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            Companies
```

So this function will give the error: "Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "SomeId" of recursive query "Companies"". I know that I can fix it with just replace "NULL AS SomeId" with "CAST(NULL AS uniqueidentifier)". But why do the anchor need to know that it is a uniqueidentifier when the parentCompanyId don't need to know that it is an int? Is it because a uniqueidentifier is a object and the int is a value type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NULL` is assumed by default to be an `int` which is why you don't have to cast that one explicitly.

You can see this from

```
SELECT NULL AS FOO INTO BAR;

SELECT DATA_TYPE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME='FOO'AND TABLE_NAME='BAR';
```