# SQL Server - Get Root node from hierarchical table

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I need to get root node of hierarchical table (has PARENT_ID = NULL):

```
ID | PARENT_ID 
60   NULL
21   60
11   NULL
23   11
24   21
25   23
14   24
13   25
```

I want this result:

```
ID | PARENT_ID | ROOT_ID |
-------------------------
1      NULL       NULL
2         1          1
3         1          1
4         2          1
5         4          1
6       NULL    NULL
7         6          6
8         7          6
```

Is CTE a good way? How can I create it?

Obiviusly I could have more the one root node. I have to get root node for each node.

This is what I did:

```
;WITH RCTE AS
(
    SELECT  ID, PARENT_ID, ID as ROOT_ID
    FROM TABLE r1
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TABLE r2 WHERE r2.ID = r1.PARENT_ID)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT rh.ID, rh.PARENT_ID, 
    CASE 
        WHEN rc.ROOT_ID = rh.ID then NULL
        ELSE ROOT_ID
    END
    FROM dbo.TABLE rh
    INNER JOIN RCTE rc ON rc.ID = rh.PARENT_ID
)
select distinct ID, PARENT_ID,  
CASE WHEN ROOT_ID = ID THEN NULL
else ROOT_ID
end ROOT_ID
from RCTE
```

But this is the result:

```
ID | PARENT_ID | ROOT_ID |
    -------------------------
    11  NULL    NULL
    60  NULL    NULL
    13  25       11
    23  11       11
    25  23       11
    13  25       60
    14  24       60
    21  60       60
    23  11       60
    24  21       60
    25  23       60
```

But as you can see, I have some duplicates:

```
ID | PARENT_ID | ROOT_ID |
    -------------------------
    13  25       60
    23  11       60
    25  23       60
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `select * from myTable where Parent_Id is null`?

Comment: Can you post some sample data you want to manipulate? What have you tried? What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: A Recursive CTE is definitely the right way to go here.

Comment: I changed my post and I added more information

Answer (score 5):

Something like the following should get you what you need.

```
 WITH recCTE AS
(
    SELECT ID, 
        Parent_ID AS original_Parent_ID, 
        Parent_ID as next_parent_id, 
        NULL as ROOT_ID,
        CASE WHEN Parent_ID IS NULL THEN 1 END AS is_root
    FROM yourtable

    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        reccte.id, 
        reccte.original_Parent_ID,
        yourtable.Parent_ID,
        CASE WHEN yourtable.Parent_ID IS NULL THEN reccte.next_parent_id ELSE reccte.ROOT_ID END,
        NULL
    FROM
        recCTE
        INNER JOIN yourtable ON reccte.next_parent_id = yourtable.ID        
)

SELECT ID, Original_Parent_ID as Parent_ID, ROOT_ID 
FROM reccte
WHERE ROOT_ID IS NOT NULL OR is_root = 1
ORDER BY ID;
```

In the recursive seed (first SELECT) we are grabbing all of the records and marking which one is already root.

Then in our recursive term (second SELECT) we go and look up the parent for the original record. If it's parent is NULL then we populate the `ROOT_ID` column.

Finally we SELECT from the recursive CTE for records that have a ROOT_ID populated or records that are already a root record.

[In action:](https://rextester.com/HEWWUP39409)

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable (ID int, Parent_ID int);

INSERT INTO yourtable VALUES
  (1, NULL),
  (2, 1),
  (3, 1),
  (4, 2), 
  (5, 4),
  (6, NULL),
  (7, 6);
```

```
 WITH recCTE AS
(
    SELECT ID, 
        Parent_ID AS original_Parent_ID, 
        Parent_ID as next_parent_id, 
        NULL as ROOT_ID,
        CASE WHEN Parent_ID IS NULL THEN 1 END AS is_root
    FROM yourtable

    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        reccte.id, 
        reccte.original_Parent_ID,
        yourtable.Parent_ID,
        CASE WHEN yourtable.Parent_ID IS NULL THEN reccte.next_parent_id ELSE reccte.ROOT_ID END,
        NULL
    FROM
        recCTE
        INNER JOIN yourtable ON reccte.next_parent_id = yourtable.ID        
)

SELECT ID, Original_Parent_ID as Parent_ID, ROOT_ID 
FROM reccte
WHERE ROOT_ID IS NOT NULL OR is_root = 1
ORDER BY ID;
```

```
+----+-----------+---------+
| ID | Parent_ID | ROOT_ID |
+----+-----------+---------+
|  1 | NULL      | NULL    |
|  2 | 1         | 1       |
|  3 | 1         | 1       |
|  4 | 2         | 1       |
|  5 | 4         | 1       |
|  6 | NULL      | NULL    |
|  7 | 6         | 6       |
+----+-----------+---------+
```

Comment: Just discovered: When having data type `uniqueidentifier` instead of `int` for the `ID` column, you have to write `convert(uniqueidentifier, NULL) as ROOT_ID` instead of `NULL as ROOT_ID`. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8562670/107625).